# No audio with adobe air 3.5 but works fine with air 3.4 - both compiled with Flash cs6

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is this a bug with 3.5 or did something change that I should know about? I tested with desktop and Android. Should I be concerned or just stick with 3.4 while the bugs are worked out?

EDIT:

It looks like the problem is that Event.ACTIVATE does not work anymore. When I place the addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction); outside, Everything works normally. The code below works with Air 3.4 .

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, fl_Activate);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, fl_Deactivate);

function fl_Activate(event:Event):void
{
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
stage.frameRate = 24;
}

function fl_Deactivate(event:Event):void
{
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
stage.frameRate = 1;
}
```

Comment: this is not much info. how do you play audio?

Comment: I added to my original post

Comment: after further testing, function fl_Activate is not initiating until after the app loses focus and returns focus for the first time. This function should happen first when the app is loaded. right?

Comment: no. activate event is thrown when the window is activated after the program creation have completed. try using creationcomplete or initialize events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I simply added

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
```

above the first function and it works ok now.